# .Net - Core project depends on .Net Framework project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

There are three different target frameworks:

```
 - .NET Framework (1)
 - .NET Core (2)
 - .NET Standard (3)
```

1 or 2 could depend on a project which has written on 3, but 1 couldn't depend on 2 or vice versa.

If we consider `WindowsBase.dll` that is written on .NET Framework (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty?view=netframework-4.8) we will see that this DLL could be used in .Net Core project.
Section `Applies to` says that this DLL could be used in both.
How it could be possible?

Comment: .NET Standard isn't a framework; ie It doesn't contain a runtime. .NET Standard is just an abstraction of APIs that can be used by a .NET Runtime like .NET Core, .NET Framework, Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, Mono, etc.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick I mean that it's a possible value for `TargetFramework`

Comment: That documentation page lacks of other supporting facts: 1) For WPF projects on .NET Core 3.0, there are necessary references (not WindowsBase.dll from .NET Framework) to enable WPF related classes. 2) Those references are automatically referenced by the SDK, if the project file matches certain criteria. Microsoft expects you to learn such facts from experiments, but I doubt how many developers at least give it a try.